# Paho Android MQTT connection lost when switch to another application

Tags: android, mqtt

I am new to Android development and I try to develop a simple application to exchange data between my PC and mobile phone using MQTT. The problem which I encountered is that when I switch between applications I lost the connection to the MQTT broker. I successfully connect to the server in onCreate() function in MainActivity and can successfully send some sample data to the PC, but only if I don't switch between applications. I was able to catch this using USB debugger, because before sending the message I check for connection using MqttAndroidClient.isConnected() and the function returns false.

How can I solve this issue? Do I have to create a separate service for MQTT functionality? Is it possible to overcome this problem without using a separate Service?

Comment: No, without a service you can't keep your MQTT client connected to the broker when you close the app or swipe it off in recent apps screen. Please note that in Android O and newer ones you would need a *foreground* service.

Comment: Thank you for your reply @HiI'mFrogatto. Do you know any samples/examples of such a service? I would like to see how to implement it correctly, because I am new both to Android development and Java and I don't understand how can I send a message using the service.

Comment: @MrMan You can use my sample code here (MQTT Service by Android Paho Library): https://stackoverflow.com/a/57652239/10976088